# c# выполнить неограниченное количество запросов

Tags: c#, база-данных

Есть программка, которая читает готовый запрос из txt файла, а потом отправляет на выполнение. Количество запросов в файле у меня всегда было определенным, каждый запрос начинается с новой строки, поэтому написал следующий код:

```
 private void автоматическаяПодгрузкаИзображенийToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string path = @"P:\DB\test2.txt";
        string s1 = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).Skip(0).First(); //Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) чтобы не было знаков вопроса вместо кириллицы
        oleComm = new OleDbCommand(s1, oleDbConn);
        oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string s2 = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).Skip(1).First();
        oleComm = new OleDbCommand(s2, oleDbConn);
        oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string s3 = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).Skip(2).First();
        oleComm = new OleDbCommand(s3, oleDbConn);
        oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
 MessageBox.Show("Данные успешно зашгружены в систему.");
    }
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в файл можно было бы записать неограниченное количество запросов?
Есть идея, что можно считать количество не пустых строк в файле и записывать это в переменную, а дальше отталкиваться от этого, но идеи как это реализовать нет.

Comment: File.ReadAllLines читает все строки, достаточно просто пройтись циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пиши в файл сколько угодно запросов с новой строки и будет работать

```
string path = @"P:\DB\test2.txt";
string[] s = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)); 

for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
{
    oleComm = new OleDbCommand(s[i], oleDbConn);
    oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Только лучше foreach

Comment: @AK, кому как угодно)

Comment: На второй строке выдает ошибку:

Comment: Ошибка 1 Неявное преобразование типа "string" в "string[]" невозможно

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает.

Comment: @Georg96, проблема в Skip(0).First()?

Comment: До 500 Мб это будет работать вероятно нормально.  На больших обьемах будут тормоза, и так же можно получить outofmemory.

Comment: Данное решение сможет выполнить ограниченое число запросов, далее последует исключение OutOfMemory. Хоть и ограниченое, но достаточно большое.

Comment: Да, проблема была именно в Skip(0).First(), которое я использовал для поиска определенной сторки. БД небольшая, так что проблем с памятью быть не должно.